# Create distance constraint between two labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am rendering two labels on a uitableviewcell. I want to increase the distance between them. 
This is the code that I have:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  NSDictionary *values  = self.viewModel.dataSet[indexPath.row];
  NSString *key         = values.allKeys.firstObject;
  id value              = values[key];
  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: cell.textLabel attribute: NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: cell.detailTextLabel
                               attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:20.0];

  .....
```

However, they don't seem to be moving.

Can anyone help me? I am not very familiar with creation of constraints by code.

Comment: try [cell layoutIfNeeded] after you add the constraints

Comment: Ah, don't just use UITableViewCell create a custom subclass with its own labels as you won't be able to change the UITableViewCell views easily or nicely.